# JEST + Vue 3 + Vuetify 3 + Vite + Testing-library/vue: SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: javascript, vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs, vuetifyjs3

First problem was:

> It is not possible to render the component in which the v-btn from vuetify is located. When testing starts, a warning appears:
>
> [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: v-btn
> If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement.
> at <AppButton ref="VTU_COMPONENT" >
> at <VTUROOT>

After that we made custom render function:

```
import { render } from "@testing-library/vue";

import { vuetify } from "./src/vuetify/vuetify";
const customRender = (component, options) => {
  return render(component, { ...options, global: { plugins: [vuetify] } });
};

export { customRender as render };
```

And got another problem:

```
 /var/www/html/node_modules/vuetify/lib/styles/main.css:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){@keyframes v-shake {
                                                                                  ^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

> 1 | import "vuetify/styles";
    | ^
  2 | import "@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css";
  3 | import { createVuetify } from "vuetify";
  4 | import { aliases, mdi } from "vuetify/iconsets/mdi";

  at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1495:14)
  at Object.require (resources/js/plugins/vuetify.js:1:1)
  at Object.require (resources/js/components/UI/testing-render.js:3:1)
  at Object.require (resources/js/components/UI/AppButton.test.js:1:1)
```

CONFIGS

AppButton.test.js

```
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/vue";
import AppButton from "./AppButton.vue";

test("render AppButton", () => {
    render(AppButton);

    screen.debug();
});
```

jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    testEnvironment: "jsdom",
    moduleFileExtensions: ["js", "json", "vue"],
    transform: {
        "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest",
        "^.+\\.vue$": "@vue/vue3-jest",
    },
    testEnvironmentOptions: {
        customExportConditions: ["node", "node-addons"],
    },
};
```

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    presets: [["@babel/preset-env", { targets: { node: "current" } }]],
};
```

Comment: Mock css files, they won't do any good in unit tests. It's unknown what's ./src/vuetify/vuetify is. It's supposed to register global comps.

Comment: I use this https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-transform-stub and its ok, but new error:
 TypeError: clone is not a function

      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:96:24)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/expect/build/index.js:14:44)
      at _expect (node_modules/@jest/expect/build/index.js:8:16)
      at createJestExpect (node_modules/@jest/expect/build/index.js:29:3)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@jest/expect/build/index.js:39:20)

Comment: The error refers to this line https://unpkg.com/browse/graceful-fs@4.2.11/graceful-fs.js#L96 . The problem is that it cannot be anything but a function here. You can see that there's not much can be found on this error message, so it's very specific to your case. Please, provide a way to reproduce the problem.

Comment: moduleNameMapper: {
        "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest",
        "^.+\\.vue$": "@vue/vue3-jest",
        "^.+.(css|styl|less|sass|scss|png|jpg|ttf|woff|woff2)$": "jest-transform-stub",
    },

Comment: i think this is wrong in config

Comment: This config shouldn't affect the deps and cause that error because of Jest defaults. Try to add `transformIgnorePatterns: ["/node_modules/"], testPathIgnorePatterns: ["/node_modules/"]` as mentioned in the docs to rule this out

Answer (score 0):

I was able to set up jest for vuetify 3.
You helped me a lot with your render function.

```js
//jest.config.js
module.exports = {
  testEnvironment: "jsdom",
  testEnvironmentOptions: {
    customExportConditions: ["node", "node-addons"]
  },
  moduleFileExtensions: [
    "js",
    "json",
    "vue"
  ],
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.(ts|js|mjs)x?$": "babel-jest",
    "^.+\\.vue$": "@vue/vue3-jest"
  },
  // setupFilesAfterEnv: ["<rootDir>/src/jest_setup_vuetify.js"],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1",
    ".+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss|png|jpg|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$":"<rootDir>/src/jest_setup_css",
    "^vuetify/components$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/vuetify/lib/components/index.mjs",
    "^vuetify/directives$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/vuetify/lib/directives/index.mjs"
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/(?!(vuetify)/)']
}
```

```js
//jest_setup_css.js
module.exports = {}
```

```js
//jest_setup_vuetify.js
import { render } from "@testing-library/vue";

import vuetify from "./plugins/vuetify";
const customRender = (component, options) => {
  return render(component, { ...options, global: { plugins: [vuetify] } });
};

export { customRender as render };
```

```js
// ./plugins/vuetify.js
// Styles
import "@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css";
// import "vuetify/styles";

// Vuetify
import { createVuetify } from "vuetify";

import * as components from 'vuetify/components'
import * as directives from 'vuetify/directives'

const vuetify = createVuetify({
  components,
  directives,
})

export default vuetify;
```

```js
//TestJest.test.js
import { render } from "../jest_setup_vuetify";
import TestJest from "./TestJest.vue";

test('renders json form', () => {
  const { debug } = render(TestJest);
  debug();
});
```

```html
//TestJest.vue
<template>
  <v-btn density="compact">Compact Button</v-btn>
</template>

<script></script>
```